# How to allow single user to use user/pass authentication in openvpn when all others will use private keys?

Tags: openvpn

I've got a Mikrotik Routerboard RB750GL which I bought to configure as an openvpn gateway for lan at the office. Unfortunately I was lured by the openvpn promise, I didn't read to carefully to know, that it only supports user/password authentication...
Anyway, I have to deal with that.
My idea is to have a LAN where every client will be on our vpn network + to have clients using software vpn clients who can connect from anywhere using their private keys.
I'm not sure openvpn can be configured to use both,from what I understand it's one way or the other, is that right?

A sample/example of ovpn server configuration to handle both user authentication methods would be welcome.

Comment: Mikrotik has no product named 'routerstation'. Also, Mikrotik products do not use PAM. Could it be a Ubiquity product? Could that be a OpenWRT setup (as could be found on Google?) What have you tried to find yourself? Have you contacted the support of your supplier?

Comment: Thanks Joffrey for pointing this out. I have used Ubiquity for years and now it's my first mikrotik and I confused the naming.

Comment: You can configure OpenVPN on Mikrotik to use username/password or x509 certificates. I think you can use both methods at the same time but you can only turn 'require certificate' on or off. Why would you like to use both authentication methods at the same time?